# Anchor tag is changing the background color of other tags when click in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Whenever i try to click a anchor tag it always change the background of others tags for a split second even though i didn't click them, where do i get things wrong?
[image]

Code Here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto  mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/rooms/">Rooms</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign-in</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it related to [tag:django] ?

Comment: I think it is happening because of your custom css. May be you are overriding nav-link or nav-item css with your custom styles.
Because when i try to reuse your code it has not such affects.

Most probably "nav-item" or li styles are overriding.

Comment: @DnD2k21 sorry for late reply, I didnt use any custom css i just use the bootstrap 5 template for navbar

Comment: @SmileKenny please share your complete code and file structure.

Answer (score 0):

try to use latest bootstrap.css and check if any css is from your custom css is overriding?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto  mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/rooms/">Rooms</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item me-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign-in</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you included also bootstrap.js the demo had the collapse feature working and you would better show that the links are not styled as the picture in the original question stated. Of course there are added styles in the real page that the OP didn't explain and it's impossible to answer in a meaningful way

Comment: @diegod sorry i will be more specific next time, i didn't use or add any custom CSS on the navbar i just use the bootstrap 5 template for navigation bar

Comment: @SmileKenny I'm commenting here despite it's not my answer, just to follow the conversation flow.. actually what you showed in the picture doesn't correspond to the html you shared. As you can see there's an hamburger icon in your code and there isn't any in the picture. So for sure it's not the same

Comment: I edited the answer just adding the reference to bootstrap.bundle.min.js so that the hamburger link will work correctly and will better show the differences between your code (included here by the user writing the answer) and the picture you shared